# Python: Break-up large function into segments

Tags: python

I am creating a Bot for Reddit. I currently only have 1 very large function and I am looking to create sub-functions to make it more readable.

Here is a rough break-down of what it does

```
def replybot():
    submissions = reversed(list(subreddit.get_new(limit=MAXPOSTS)))
    for post in submissions:
        try:
            author = post.author.name
        except AttributeError:
            print "AttributeError: Author is deleted"
            continue # Author is deleted. We don't care about this post.
        # DOES PID EXIST IN DB? IF NOT ADD IT
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM oldposts WHERE ID=?', [pid])
        sql.commit()
        if cur.fetchone(): # Post is already in the database
            continue
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO oldposts VALUES(?)', [pid])
        sql.commit()
...
```

I am looking to break the code up into segments i.e. put

```
        try:
            author = post.author.name
        except AttributeError:
            print "AttributeError: Author is deleted"
            continue # Author is deleted. We don't care about this post.
```

in it's own function and call it from within `replybot()` but I run into the issue of calling `continue`. I get `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`

Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise the error again instead of trying to continue. Either simply let it bubble to the main loop, or if you need better error handling, make your own custom error. For instance:

```
class MyNotFatalError(Exception):
    pass

def do_something():
    try:
        a, b, c = 1, 2
    except ValueError:
        raise MyNotFatalError('Something went wrong')

# In your main function
for post in submissions:
    try:
        do_something()
        do_some_other_thing()
        do_some_more()
    except MyNotFatalError as err:
        continue # we could print out the error text here
    do_some_last_thing()
```

It is probably better that way because you only catch errors you know you want to catch, and still let the program crash when there are actual bugs.

If you had simply caught `ValueError` that would also intercept and hide all other possible sources of the same kind of error.

Comment: What would I do if my code had 'continue' in it though?

Comment: In the main loop, you can use `continue` wherever you want. In the subfunctions, use `raise MyNotFatalError()` instead. If you may continue on conditions that are not actually errors, maybe rename the exception to something more meaningful, like `SkipCurrentPost`

Answer (score 3):

If you take the inner part of a loop and convert it to its own function, it's no longer in a loop. The equivalent of `continue` in a loop, for a function, is `return` (i.e. terminate this iteration (which is now a function call) early).

Comment: Won't `return` continue running the rest of the (large) function though? I want to skip to the next iteration

Comment: @Bijan: hmm then you'll want to return a meaningful value, and check it, and `continue`. e.g. say the snippet you took out is called `get_author()`, you'd replace `author = post.author.name` with `return post.author.name`, and instead of the `continue` you do `return None`. Then in the calling code, you do `author = get_author()` and `if not author: continue`.

Answer (score 1):

as Claudiu said, when you broke inner commands into it's own function; It's not no longer in the loop and your code will be look like this:

```
def isNotAuthorDeleted(post):
    try:
        author = post.author.name
        return author 
    except AttributeError:
        print "AttributeError: Author is deleted"
        return false
```

and your loop will be:

```
for post in submissions:
    if not isNotAuthorDeleted(post):
        continue
```